# store large String in android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, file

I have an object like:

```
class Object{
int id;
String content;
String path;
}
```

content usually has a length 1M~100M.

I get data from ble device and store them in object .I update together when I'm in good net.

I have 2 solutions to store this:

1. store content in file and put path in database.

When I want to upload ,I should read file and combine content with id to a String .And upload the String.

When I want to update, I need to change file and its name and update path in database.

2. store content directly in database.I would create a new  database rather than use the app's original one.

When I want to upload ,I just serialize the Object query from database and upload it.

When I want to update,I just update database.

Which one is better?

Comment: I'm sorry, what's your question?

Comment: I want to know which solution is better.

Comment: could you make your question clear ?

Comment: Instead of combining the content with id to a string. Second one would be the best, storing in database by serialize would be the best, it will take less time and more efficient way.

Comment: "Better" is subjective, as long as you do not tell us your technical goals.

Comment: I get data from ble device and store them in object.I will update them when I get good net.